# Is Mars on SpatialReference.org (srid 49901) broken?

Tags: coordinate-system

Just noticed there were seemingly duplicate SRSIDs for Mars [49900](http://spatialreference.org/ref/iau2000/49900/) and [49901](http://spatialreference.org/ref/iau2000/49901/) on spatialreference.org. I saw they were both generating the same PostGIS insert statements with only a different SRIDs changed. Wanting to know more I found [Interoperability in Planetary Research for Geospatial Data Analysis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.02683.pdf), it shows

> IAU2000 49900 Mars2000, aerocentric latitudes, positive East longitudes
>
> IAU2000 49901 Mars2000, aerographic latitudes, **positive West longitudes**

That seems to indicate they're different. Shouldn't that generate a [`+axis=wnu`](http://proj4.org/parameters.html) in the [pro4j for 49901](http://spatialreference.org/ref/iau2000/49901/proj4/)? Currently, it only shows,

```
+proj=longlat +a=3396190 +b=3376200 +no_defs
```

Comment: Is spatialreference.org being maintained? About the only thing you can do is contact any maintainers and ask them to fix it.